# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribeNewsletter' of undefined at newsletter.component.ts.NewsletterComponent.subscribeNewsletter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting this error : `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribeNewsletter' of undefined at NewsletterComponent.subscribeNewsletter (newsletter.component.ts:47)` when I try to create a service to subscribe to a newsletter from a form.

This is my `NewsletterComponent` :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsletterService } from '../common/service/newsletter.service';
import { NewsletterDto } from '../common/model/dto/newsletter-dto';
import { FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-user-cmp',
    templateUrl: 'newsletter.component.html'
})

export class NewsletterComponent implements OnInit {

    newsletterService: NewsletterService;
    newsletterForm: FormGroup;
    newsletter: NewsletterDto;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.newsletterForm = new FormGroup({
      'subscribe': new FormControl(null),
    });

        }


    constructor() {}

        subscribeNewsletter(): void {
            this.newsletter = {
            subscribe: this.newsletterForm.controls['subscribe'].value
            };
            this.newsletterService.subscribeNewsletter(this.newsletter).subscribe(newsletter => this.newsletter = newsletter);
        }
  }
```

And this is my `NewsletterService` :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { NewsletterDto } from '../model/dto/newsletter-dto';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewsletterService {

  private newsletterUrl = 'rest/newsletter/subscription';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  subscribeNewsletter(newsletter: NewsletterDto): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http
      .post(this.newsletterUrl, newsletter, options).pipe(
        map((res: any) => res.json()),
        catchError(<T>(error: any, result?: T) => {
          console.log(error);
          return of(result as T);
        })
      );
  }

}
```

I don't really get where's the problem ? Can anyone enlighten me a little bit ? Thanks !

Comment: You forgot to inject the `newsletterService` ?

Comment: Yes, it was that ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject the service in `constructor`

```
constructor(public newsletterService: NewsletterService) {
   /* do the construction stuff */
}
```

Make sure to remove the other `newsletterService` property defined before costructor.

Answer (score 2):

In your component you declare

```
newsletterService: NewsletterService;
```

It's means  newsletterService type is NewsletterService. But you are not creating any instance of NewsletterService class.

In your service subscribeNewsletter method can be accessible via object, So first you need to create new instance of your service.

You can do it on your component just like

```
constructor(private newsletterService: NewsletterService) { }
```

and remove other declaration which you already given.

This dependency injector automatically create instance if not present.

Other way you can do this but that's not good way.

```
newsletterService: NewsletterService=new NewsletterService();
```